# How to connect Rasberry Pi 3 to wireless keyboard on 1st installation

Tags: pi-3b+

Sorry, not sure if this is the right forum for the question.

I have just purchased `Rasberry  Pi 3` and a wireless keyboard. How do I connect the keyboard to `pi` during first boot/installation of `pi` board? Without a keyboard, I can't interact with `pi` to set up the wireless keyboard!

Do I need a wired keyboard for 1st installation and to connect to wireless keyboard and afterwards I can use the wireless keyboard?

Comment: Most wireless keyboard has a USB dongle, connect that to the Raspberry Pi. Or perhaps adding more info like keyboard type, wireless technology could increase your chance to get a propper answer.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a wired keyboard, presuming the wireless keyboard you have is a standard USB style one.  This does not include bluetooth keyboards, which you need to be able to log in and pair.  However, you can do that via `ssh`, if you have another machine you can connect from.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a wired keyboard (and preferrably also a wired mouse) to do the first-time setup.

Later you can set up a wireless (bluetooth-)keyboard.

Comment: This is false WRT standard USB wireless keyboards.  They will work fine on first boot.

Comment: Crap, always forget about those.